# Can't add a subclass in XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib, ios7.1

I have a scroll view that loads a series of XIBS as pages. One of the XIBs (iPhoneFirstPage) is a UIView that has a twitter button that I would like to link to another ViewController in the XIB. The only problem is when I create a subclass of UIView to add an IBAction to the button, the subclass doesn't show up under the "Custom Class" drop down on the UIView. How would I do this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Save both files (Cmd + S) and try again.
- Cmd+Shift+K to clean and try again.
- Just type the name in--it should build fine assuming you've typed the right name and it can find the file.
- Restart Xcode and try again.

Note: This is a list of 4 different things to try.  Any single one of them should correct the problem individually--you shouldn't necessarily need to do all 4 things.